# Thinking sphinx index updates but don't search new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a rake task `RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:index`, which is executed every 3 hours by Cron, but nothing changes. When I call same query in the command line, nothing happened. And only when I call `RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:rebuild`, changes is applied. But why? Documentation said that ts:rebuild should be called if table structure is changed. But when only data rows is added, should be called ts:index. What could be wrong with it?

Comment: What happens if you call ts:index from the command-line, as opposed to via cron? Do you have any logs from cron when it's calling that task? And what versions of Thinking Sphinx and Sphinx are you using?

Comment: If I call ts:index from command line, it writes, that all ok, all records are indexed, but on site nothing changes. Cron writes nothing, TS version: 3.0.5, sphinx version 2.0.8-release (r3831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is Sphinx's command-line indexer tool is not available in the PATH for cron. I'd recommend setting the PATH environment variable within your cron configuration to include the folder wherever `indexer` is located (which can be found by running `which indexer` when you're logged in).